# My computer wont install Ubuntu after i nuked my laptop

Tags: boot, laptop

I recently nuked my laptop with DBAN so i can install Ubuntu. I put the disk and it shows Ubuntu and let me choose install or test it out but no matter what is choose it stays at the Ubuntu loading screen but never loads up.

Specs

Ubuntu 12.04

Acer Laptop

Comment: Have you nuked the UEFI partition as well? You would need that unless in Legacy Mode. Make sure you are using the AMD64 (64bit) version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Those aren't specs. That is a make and an operating system. If you give the Acer model number at least the specs can be looked up.

Answer (score 0):

Please go into the BIOS and change the UEFI/Legacy BIOS setting to Legacy BIOS (Acer may call it something different).

Comment: what am i changing

Comment: There should be an item named something like UEFI/Legacy BIOS - which you would change to Legacy BIOS, instead of UEFI.

Comment: Ide mode is legacy